# Wipe an IMAP folder without having to sync everything

Tags: email, thunderbird, imap

My local ISP has mixed POP/IMAP boxes and a bad habit of moving possible spam to a folder on IMAP which means that I have to configure Thunderbird to use IMAP instead of POP and die from boredom until it syncs the entire folder. Last time there were more than six thousand emails and that takes a while even if you're on broadband.

So my question is if there's an email client or a method that can help me to wipe the offending folder without having to sync it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set the IMAP to only download headers. That should go fairly quick even if there are several thousand emails. Remember to "purge" the deleted emails after you delete them - otherwise they are still in your mailbox in IMAP.

Comment: That did the trick, just for those using thunderbird remember to disable the spam checking options when configuring the account

Comment: Thanks for the reminder on purging ;-) I just needed that!

Comment: Why don't people like to up-vote on superuser.com??

Answer (score 1):

As a [side-note](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/HP100804201033.aspx) to Sanjay's post:

Manually purge deleted items

To permanently delete the items marked for deletion, do the following:

1. Click a folder in your IMAP e-mail
           account.
2. On the Edit menu, point to
3. Purge Deleted Messages. Do one of
           the following:

[image]

- Click Purge Marked Items in "folder".
  Only items marked for deletion in the
  folder that you are in are purged
  from the IMAP mail server.
- Click Purge Marked Items in "e-mail
  account". All items marked for
  deletion in any folder for this IMAP
  e-mail account are purged from the
  IMAP mail server.
- Click Purge Marked Items in All
  Accounts. All items marked for
  deletion in any folder for any IMAP
  e-mail account are purged from the
  IMAP mail server.